# Style aspx navigationmenu with submenu on hover

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

This is how my menu looks like:

[image]

I tried to change the width of the SUB1 button but failed. SUB2 has the right width but should be on the left. I think I'm missing a CSS class for the submenu. The menu should look like this:

[image]

I tried around changing the `ul` `li` and `a` in the `site.css` but can't reach the goal.

aspx:

```
<asp:Menu ID="StartMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menuStart" EnableViewState="false"
          IncludeStyleBlock="true" Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="List"
          StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" StaticSelectedStyle-BackColor="#b90276">
    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="20" VerticalPadding="10" />
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="ITEM1" >
            <asp:MenuItem Text="SUB1"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="SUB2"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="ITEM2"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#B90276"></StaticSelectedStyle>
</asp:Menu>
```

```css
div.menuStart {
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
}

div.menuStart ul {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

div.menuStart a,
a:visited {
  background-color: #7d8790;
  border-top: 4px #ffffff solid;
  border-right: 4px #ffffff solid;
  border-bottom: 4px #ffffff solid;
  border-left: 4px #ffffff solid;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: normal;
  line-height: 1.35em;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: "Verdana";
  font-size: 20px;
}

div.menuStart li~li {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

div.menuStart ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #b90276;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.menuStart ul li a:active {
  background-color: #b90276;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuStart" id="MainContent_StartMenu" style="float: left;">
  <ul class="level1 static" tabindex="0" role="menubar" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;">
    <li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="MainContent_StartMenu:submenu:21" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a class="level1 static" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$StartMenu','ITEM1')" tabindex="-1">ITEM1</a>
      <ul class="level2 dynamic" id="MainContent_StartMenu:submenu:21" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
        <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dynamic" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$StartMenu','ITEM1\\SUB1')" tabindex="-1">SUB1</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dynamic" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$StartMenu','ITEM1\\SUB2')" tabindex="-1">SUB2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a class="level1 static" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$StartMenu','ITEM2')" tabindex="-1">ITEM2</a></li>
    <li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="MainContent_StartMenu:submenu:26" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a class="level1 static" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$StartMenu','ITEM3')" tabindex="-1">ITEM3</a>
      <ul class="level2 dynamic" id="MainContent_StartMenu:submenu:26" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
        <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dynamic" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$StartMenu','ITEM3\\SUB1')" tabindex="-1">SUB1</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dynamic" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$StartMenu','ITEM3\\SUB2')" tabindex="-1">SUB2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pete the picture is the rendered page

Comment: @Pete I added the html above